# how to plot a cylinder in matlab having radius 1 with axis from point (1,0,0) to (1,0,3)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have copied and pasted this code from matlab documentation on the command window

```
plot(plot::Cylinder(a, [0, 0, a], [0, 0, 3 - a],
                a = 1 .. 2))
```

[image]
but it produces the error:

```
 plot(plot::Cylinder(a, [0, 0, a], [0, 0, 3 - a],
       |
 Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

Why?

So how can I plot a cylinder in matlab having radius 1 with axis from point (1,0,0) to (1,0,3)?
I have used the code:

```
[x,y,z]=cylinder(1);
x1=x+1;
surf(x1,y,z)
```

but it just considers the axis from point (1,0,0) to (1,0,1)
how can I plot a cylinder and specify arbitrary range for the length of its axis?

Comment: The documentation is for MuPAD, which is part of the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: It will require some matrix multiplication with rotation/translation/scaling matrices, I have flagged a duplicate that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are issuing this command from the [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/mupad.html) environment in  Matlab. This is not a valid syntax for Matlab so it throws an error.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

On [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-cylinder.html) site they say use this function only in MuPAD Notebook Interface. Because This functionality does not run in MATLAB.

This is the snapshot from mathworks site.
[image]

Comment: i edited my question